# Issues running Spark application on ASW with compute optimized instances

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-spark, mapreduce, rdd, distributed-computing

Hello I'm comparing the performances of my Spark algorithm on two different clusters. One with more computational power and one with more memory efficiency.

1. Cluster 1 has 5 nodes of AWS instances **c4.xlarge** with 4 vCPU and
   7.5GiB of main memory.
2. Cluster 2 has 5 nodes of AWS instances **r4.xlarge** with 4 vCPU and 30.5 GiB of main memory.

My code gets divided into 13 stages but only the last 5 stages are actually those I need to take care of performance of. These five below:

[image]

The picture above shows the statistics of the stages of running my code on cluster 2 (memory efficiency) you can see Stage 11 and 13 take few minutes because a **flatMap** and **map** respectively do some heavy sequential work on lists.

Since the job stage 11 and 13 do is sequential in each partition I'd expect to get better performances for those 2 stages using cluster 1 (compute efficiency) but what I actually got when running on cluster 1 is that the last 3 stages run only 32 tasks (so only 32 partitions) and the running time was slower, like 2 minutes more for each stage.

I realized that only 3 executors were running so actually only 3 of 4 instances were working on my problem. Then what I did was submitting the app this way:

```
spark-submit --master yarn --deploy-mode cluster —-num—executors 4 --executor-cores 4 --class myclass myjar myparams
```

So I thought forcing the number of executors to `—-num—executors 4` would force the 4th node to get one executor but nothing to do. That didn't work neither. Only 3 executors were active on 3 instances.

I'm sure the problem is this one. Don't you think sequential stages should run faster on cluster 1? Is the problem that cluster 1 has less main memory according to you?

Thank you for cooperating with me in finding an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using resources optimally on EMR requires a bit of configuration-tweaking and also a bit of knowledge as to how YARN works. I highly recommend reading [this blog post](http://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2015/03/how-to-tune-your-apache-spark-jobs-part-2/) from Cloudera to get a overview of how to tune your applications with YARN.

Anyway, in this particular case, the reason why you only see 3 executors instead of 4, is because you have specified that each executor should have 4 cores (with the flag `--executor-cores 4`). Since there are only 4 cores available on each worker and since YARN takes 1 core on one of the workers to run the application manager, you will essentially only have 3 workers with 4 cores available and 1 worker with 3 cores available. The worker with 3 cores available cannot run an executor that requires 4 cores and thus an executor is simply not stated on this worker. This leaves you with 3 executors.

Anyway, the aforementioned blog post describes this in details :)

Oh, and in terms of which type cluster will run faster, you have to test it. I follow your theoretical thinking, but I have long since given up on trying to predict which type of clusters will be better for a specific task. Truth is that unless fully understand how Spark creates it's execution plans, you are essentially just guessing. I recommend that you test different instances types and use Ganglia to monitor how your clusters utilize the different resources.